# I don't know how to integrate this JQuery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/kFu52/1/

Can someone tell me what I do wrong?
This is what I came up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>Demo</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="Untitled-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script>
 $('.thumbs img').hover(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', url);
});
</script>


<div class="thumbs">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/city/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
</div>

<div class="main-img">
    <img id="main" src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400"/>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot, I'm obviously very new to JQuery.

Comment: wrap your code inside doc ready.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in dom ready event. Otherwise your script will execute before the elements has been rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbs img').hover(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#main').attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). This will run your code inside the `callback` of `ready` after all the elements in your page are loaded and the `hover` event is binded on `img` inside `.thumb`.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbs img').hover(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#main').attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler. Currently your code execute before DOM is loaded. Rest of your code works.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.thumbs img').hover(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


<div class="thumbs">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/200/400" width="50" height="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/city/200/400" width="50" height="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400" width="50" height="50" />
</div>

<div class="main-img">
  <img id="main" src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answers all valid, I'm used to use the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // your code here.
});
```

<s>I don't much about the difference, I simple like this one better than `ready`. If someone is willing to give more info in the comment, I'll edit my answer.</s>

This syntax allows you to use other JS library that also use `$` as identifier. Wrap all your jQuery code inside and you will be facing no conflict with another library.
From [jQuery's API](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> However, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code:

Comment: Just go through the https://api.jquery.com/ready/ _When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call $.noConflict() to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the $ shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write jQuery each time we would normally write $. However, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code:_

Comment: @Satpal I can see they're mentionning `jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {` but it is slightly different from what I provided. Do you happen to know the difference between those two?

Comment: haven't you seen `$(function() { .. })` which is equivalent

Comment: Oh right, I did see it but I thought it was different as nothing is passed as an argument.